# Why does SPARQL LIMIT on Inner Query seem to limit the outer query under RDF4J?

Tags: sparql, rdf4j

I'm using RDF4J version 2.2.2 workbench and server under Windows 10.  I need to use an inner query to limit results.  My particular application is in accumulating an event concept from a series of correlated reports.  Each report has a time stamp as one of its properties.  I need the inner query with a `LIMIT` and an `ORDER BY` to get the latest time stamp from the reports contributing each event.  The event is established by a triple in the outer query. Since the full application is rather complex, I've come up with a simple case to illustrate my question.  Basically, I'm expecting the outer query to produce several results with an inner query limited to 1, but the `LIMIT` seems to be applied to the outer query.   I'm wondering why I'm getting only one result when I expect more.  In the example case herein, I expect two results but get only one...

The example case is set up in RDF4J workbench using an repository with RDFS+SPIN support.

1. Clear the repository (RDF4J workbench Modify/Clear).
2. Load the [Nuvio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NK22l0JWrYwiCMEEeJxvHhEzL0mlMbFa) ontology version 1.0.0 using the workbench Modify/Add function
3. Set up the test condition using the following SPARQL update query using the RDF4J Modify/SPARQL Update function.

   ```
   PREFIX Nuvio: <http://cogradio.org/ont/Nuvio.owl#>
   PREFIX inst: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Sharing/Instantiations#>
   PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

   INSERT {
       inst:aTestObject1 Nuvio:hasValue _:b0 ;
           Nuvio:hasValue _:b1 .
       inst:aTestObject2 Nuvio:hasValue _:b2 ;
           Nuvio:hasValue _:b3 .

       _:b0 Nuvio:hasDataValue "2017-11-13T13:46:00.000-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
       _:b1 Nuvio:hasDataValue "2017-11-13T13:46:01.000-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
       _:b2 Nuvio:hasDataValue "2017-11-13T13:46:02.000-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
       _:b3 Nuvio:hasDataValue "2017-11-13T13:46:03.000-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
   }
   WHERE {
   }
   ```
4. Now run the following SPARQL Query using the RDF4J Workbench Explore/Query function:

   ```
   PREFIX Nuvio: <http://cogradio.org/ont/Nuvio.owl#>

   SELECT DISTINCT *
   WHERE {
     ?o a Nuvio:Quantity .
     ?o Nuvio:hasValue/Nuvio:hasDataValue ?value .
   }
   ```

   which produces the expected four results (both time stamps for both test individuals):
   [image: Results as expected from first query]
5. Now attempt to limit the results to one time stamp per individual (`inst:aTestObject1` and `inst:aTestObject2`) using the following query containing an inner query (a simple extension of the first query):

   ```
   PREFIX Nuvio: <http://cogradio.org/ont/Nuvio.owl#>

   SELECT DISTINCT *
   WHERE {
     ?o a Nuvio:Quantity .
     {
       SELECT DISTINCT *
       WHERE {
         ?o Nuvio:hasValue/Nuvio:hasDataValue ?value .
       } LIMIT 1
     }
   }
   ```

   which produces only one result:

   [image: unexpected single result from second query when two results expected]

   I'm expecting two results, one for each of `inst:aTestObject1` and `inst:aTestObject2` since each has two timestamps.  But I only get a result for `inst:aTestObject2`.  Why only one?

Comment: I hope you know that the **inner query is always executed first**?

Comment: If you want to have one timestamp per test object you have to use `GROUP BY` by the test objects and then use an aggregate function like `SAMPLE`

Comment: @AKSW, thank you.  I "knew" about the inner query executing first, but I didn't think it through.  So, I'll work from your second comment.  If I can get that working the way I want, I'll post the resulting query as an answer.

Comment: Ok, cool! I can see from your answer that you already found the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Following @AKSW's comment that the inner select is always evaluated first and recovering from my brain fade, the solution to what I wanted (each test object with the latest `xsd:dateTime` value) can be achieved using the following simple query...

```
PREFIX Nuvio: <http://cogradio.org/ont/Nuvio.owl#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?o (MAX(?value) as ?maxValue)
WHERE {
  ?o a Nuvio:Quantity .
  ?o Nuvio:hasValue/Nuvio:hasDataValue ?value .
} GROUP BY ?o
```

Which returns the desired two results:

[image: desired query results]

Thanks @AKSW.